# connecting polygons with nearest neighbor lines to create a cuttable stencil

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, nearest-neighbor, osmnx

My Python script connects [separate polygons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RS5Y4.png) with "connector lines" based on a nearest neighbor algorithm so I can cut them out as *one* shape like this [connected polygons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myX7v.png).

This works fine but I have three questions:

- The lines are actually *not* the closest connection between the polygons. Why doesn't the algorithm find the red line (inserted manually) but the *wrong* black line? See here:[wrong nearest neighbor line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bleRf.gif) - Is it possible that the nearest point function only connects to nodes but not to points on a polygon line? That would explain the offset?
- To create a stable stencil that's not too "wobbly", I want to add [additional connection lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wWs3.gif). Obviously a very different algorithm is needed. How do I define "wobbly", what could be the criteria to find these connections that would make the stencil more stable? I believe the answer lies in an approach to find the shortest path between polygon points and then comparing then shortest path length with the length of a direct line connection. I would then  add the connections that a) have the highest percentage in shorteing the path by going direct and b) that are above a treshold inn total "saving". this would have to be done iteratively as a new connection will change the calcualtion for all others paths. I have found a number of interesting but complex algorithms that address the first part of the problem: finding a shortest path within one polygon:
- https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d59f/b891cac975a3b1d627e6e096916e35235ff2.pdf
- https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.100.1319&rep=rep1&type=pdf

3. A much simpler question: The part of the script that creates the geodataframe with the three polygons seems awfully complicated. I am sure there are much easier ways to do it?

```
import osmnx as ox
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon, LineString
from shapely.ops import nearest_points

box=(51.4616,51.4522, -0.1354, -0.1628)

p1lat=[51.4596626, 51.4580315, 51.4579446, 51.4589807, 51.4599099, 51.4595690, 51.4587935, 51.4578643, 51.4577373, 51.4590141, 51.4603845, 51.4603578, 51.4596626]
p1long=[-0.1544094,-0.1543021,-0.1536155,-0.1533473,-0.1532292,-0.1521242,-0.1519632,-0.1526713,-0.1520705,-0.1510084,-0.1519740,-0.1538301,-0.1544094]
p1=Polygon(zip(p1long,p1lat))
p2lat=[51.4582654, 51.4572092, 51.4566744, 51.4562599, 51.4561930, 51.4569953, 51.4585930, 51.4594553, 51.4594553, 51.4580983, 51.4569084, 51.4567813, 51.4569552, 51.4571758, 51.4579379, 51.4581652, 51.4582989, 51.4585796, 51.4587601, 51.4582654]
p2long=[-0.1493561,-0.1497531,-0.1492059,-0.1475108,-0.1460624,-0.1456332,-0.1454616,-0.1456439,-0.1460516,-0.1460302,-0.1463413,-0.1471460,-0.1477575,-0.1486588,-0.1486266,-0.1473176,-0.1467168,-0.1466846,-0.1468456,-0.1493561,]
p2=Polygon(zip(p2long,p2lat))
p3lat=[51.4608859, 51.4608424, 51.4604213, 51.4600904, 51.4600235, 51.4602241, 51.4603110, 51.4606385, 51.4606185, 51.4608859]
p3long=[-0.1481116,-0.1507562,-0.1511103,-0.1510674,-0.1480097,-0.1480311,-0.1504290,-0.1504987, -0.1480740,-0.1481116]
p3=Polygon(zip(p3long,p3lat))

polygons = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], geometry=[p1])
polygons=polygons.append(gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], geometry=[p2]))
polygons=polygons.append(gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], geometry=[p3]))
polygons.set_crs(epsg=4326, inplace=True)

def createcard(layer,lcolor, framewidth, connectorwidth):
  dflines = gpd.GeoDataFrame(columns=['ID','Location','geometry']) #connector lines
  dfframes =gpd.GeoDataFrame(columns=['ID','Location','geometry']) #frames
  df=layer
  df=df.dissolve().explode()
  df.insert(1,'nearest_geometry', None)
  df.insert(2,'queried_geometry', None)
  while df.shape[0]>1: #add connector lines to the dataframe, explode and dissolve until therev is only 1 polygon, i.e. everything is connected
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        point = row.geometry
        multipoint = df.drop(index, axis=0).geometry.unary_union
        queried_geom, nearest_geom = nearest_points(point, multipoint)
        df.loc[index, 'nearest_geometry'] = nearest_geom
        df.loc[index, 'queried_geometry'] = queried_geom
        x=LineString([nearest_geom,queried_geom]).buffer(connectorwidth)
        dflines=dflines.append({'geometry' : x, 'ID':'2','Location':'test'},ignore_index=True)
    df=df.append(dflines).dissolve().explode() # add the connector lines to the df and make it one polygon 
  fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))
  ox.plot.plot_footprints(df, ax=ax, bbox=box ,  color=lcolor, alpha=1, bgcolor='#FFFF', save=True, show=False, close=False)
```

Google Colab notebook with the code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1As0JIq6zxqsjeaVHmpxcRcccy7bqUIjy?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

It's got nothing to do in with the connector lines, but with something much more fundamental that I disregarded: projections. In my example above the whole map was distorted, but I only noticed by looking at what I added t ok the map, connector lines. All projections are distorted, you need to choose the right one for your purposes. I still need to learn a lot more about projections, but fwiw I ended up creating a custom UTM CRS with the center of my map as the 0,0 coordinates of the UTM CRS.